# How to Restrict unassigned variable to not get from POJO to JSON?

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have a class A, with two variable varOne, varTwo,
While assigning I only assigned varTwo, but when converting to JSON  I'm getting both the value
one which was unassigned is as null.
What can I do to restrict varOne. if varOne is unassigned the I don't want it at all in Json.

I tried reconstruct the JSON. but feels like could do better.

Comment: Please have a look : to provide minimal reproducible code .
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: no ............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` above the class